# Problem with using case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

Tags: c

while coding a game called fanorona I encountered a problem with switching from the mode player (when its his turn) and when its the turn of the machine.

I think whats posing the problem is the : case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

should I close the case before the machine role part . or what exactly should I do .

```
  if(machine==0){
         case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `if` and `switch ... case`. Decide on one.
Without a MRE (minimal reproducable example,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) this does not get any more detailed, sorry.